# Common patterns for Observable data layer on iOS

Tags: android, ios, swift-language, observer-pattern, kotlin

I am working on learning native iOS development in Swift, and I am trying to find something that is similar to what I've learned in Android development with Kotlin.

In particular I am referring to the concept of having the db as the "single source of truth", that is advertised by the Android team as one of the main points of their recommended [app architecture](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide). This is possible by the use of `LiveData`, an observable data holder, and `Room`, a persistence library based on SQLite that returns `LiveData` objects. Those objects are observed in the UI layer to display data to the user. With this architecture, the typical Repository call looks something like this:

```
/**
 * The database serves as the single source of truth.
 * Therefore UI can receive data updates from database only.
 * Function notify UI about:
 * [Result.Status.SUCCESS] - with data from database
 * [Result.Status.ERROR] - if error has occurred from any source
 * [Result.Status.LOADING]
 */
fun <T, A> resultLiveData(databaseQuery: () -> LiveData<T>,
                          networkCall: suspend () -> Result<A>,
                          saveCallResult: suspend (A) -> Unit): LiveData<Result<T>> =
        liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
            emit(Result.loading<T>())
            val source = databaseQuery.invoke().map { Result.success(it) }
            emitSource(source)

            val responseStatus = networkCall.invoke()
            if (responseStatus.status == SUCCESS) {
                saveCallResult(responseStatus.data!!)
            } else if (responseStatus.status == ERROR) {
                emit(Result.error<T>(responseStatus.message!!))
                emitSource(source)
            }
        }
```

(taken from [here](https://proandroiddev.com/android-architecture-starring-kotlin-coroutines-jetpack-mvvm-room-paging-retrofit-and-dagger-7749b2bae5f7))

This allows also to encapsulate both the data and its loading status in a single object (`Result` in the example), so the UI can start showing the old data coming from the DB while the new one is retrieved from the network, and the status as well.

I have been looking for something similar in iOS but it seems that there is no straightforward solution. The closest to it seems to be a combination of `Realm` or `CoreData` for the data layer, and then `RxSwift` for the observable bits. This seems to involve quite some more coordination between the different parts, and not as straightforward as in Android.

Am I missing maybe an easier path in doing what I need?

Comment: You just use a Notification and a NotificationHandler. No need for RxSwift or any other library. Built into iOS since about 2007.

Comment: I am considering to apply technique mentioned in https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift/blob/master/README.md#valueobservation

Comment: Store your model in CoreData and use notifications: https://cocoacasts.com/how-to-observe-a-managed-object-context